# Nuxt.js - Axios crashes with 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm building a website using Nuxt Frontend + Node Backend.

Currently, I've implemented `nuxtServerInit` code inside Vuex store file.

The web seems working without error, but it often crashes with the following error below...

```
 WARN  Cannot stringify a function transformRequest                                                                                                                                               21:59:08


 WARN  Cannot stringify a function transformResponse                                                                                                                                              21:59:08


 WARN  Cannot stringify a function httpAdapter                                                                                                                                                    21:59:08


 WARN  Cannot stringify a function validateStatus                                                                                                                                                 21:59:08


 WARN  Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs ClientRequest                                                                                                                                         21:59:08


 WARN  Cannot stringify a function
```

I've been searching for the cause of this issue since few days agao, and I thought that the cause might be coming from using both `context.app.$axios` and `this.$axios` in a single Vuex file like below.

```js
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
    const postsArray = []
    const data = await context.app.$axios.$get(
      process.env.DEV_URL + '/articles/top-five-views'
    )

    for (const key in data.postings) {
      postsArray.push({ ...data.postings[key], id: key })
    }

    return vuexContext.commit('setTopFivePosts', postsArray)
  },
  async getArticles(vuexContext, context) {
    const articles = []
    const data = await this.$axios.$get(
      process.env.DEV_URL + '/articles/popular'
    )

    for (const key in data.postings) {
      articles.push({ ...data.postings[key], id: key })
    }
    return vuexContext.commit('getArticles', articles)
  }
}
```

Should I use `this.$axios` instead of `context.app.$axios`?? 
If I should, what is the difference between these two? (Because I feel like `this` is also pointing to `context.app`...)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are you using `console.log()` somewhere in here? I've only ever seen those logs out of `nuxt` when you `console.log(context)`

Comment: Nope. Not in vuex file. If console log exists in other files, could this also affect this?

Comment: just use axios.get/post

Comment: @StevenYoo I am having the same issue. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Hey @FooBar , are you using `express-rate-limit` package in your app? I've resolved this issue by simply increasing the rate-limit max value from 100 to 1000. This may not be the best solution, but so far everything works fine.

Comment: Hey Steven. No I don't bro

Comment: How does your code look like?